# How to fit an error message in div table?

Tags: knockout.js

I am generating dynamic table(employee details) using knockout ko bindings as shown in below 
For Eg:
[image]

If the EmpDetails is empty then i want show an error message "No Data" in the div.
I have used knockout visible binding to display the error message.

Currently i am displaying in single line

Employee details:
        No Data

Expected:fit the "No Data" message in 5 rows space.

[image]

Refer the below code:

```
<div class="empSection" data-bind="visible:displayData">
        <span>Employee Details:</span>
        <table class="empTable" border="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="empTableHeader">NAME</th>
                    <th class="empTableHeader">EMPNO</th>
                    <th class="empTableHeader">DEPT</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: EmpDetails">
                <tr>
                    <td class="empName" data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                    <td class="empNo" data-bind="text: emono"></td>
                    <td class="empDept" data-bind="text: dept"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

</div>

<div class="empSection" data-bind="visible:ErrorMsg, text:"No Data">
```

Any suggestions on this please??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please post your viewModel js

Comment: View Model: Var vm={ EmpDetails:ko.oservablearray(),ErrorMsg:ko.oservable(true),displayData:ko.observable(true),}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just negate displayData value and set padding or height to fill space that is equal to 5 row height:

```
<div class="empSection" style="padding: 50px 0; text-align: center;" data-bind="visible:!displayData()">
  No data
</div>
```